# Can I make an onclick function not execute if the click opens a link in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a large  that show a random piece of text from a .json - file whenever it is clicked. Now sometimes the text involves links, which are set to open in a new tab. Works perfectly fine!

However, I'd like to not have the onclick function execute, when a new tab is opened. The same as if the user opens the link by right-clicking and opening in a new tab.

Is that possible using plain javascript? I include the selectPodcast - function to show how the link is generated.

As I'm at it: I haven't been programming for long and I'd love to know what my code looks like to an experienced programmer. I'd imagine it's kinda cute, like when a child starts forming sentences :-)

I tried to add a.onclick = "return false;"; to the selectPodcast - function, but that didn't work.

```
function getPodcast() {
    var url = "json/podcasts.json";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url);
    request.onload = function() {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            selectPodcast(request.responseText);
        }
    };
    request.send(null);
};

function selectPodcast(responseText) {
    var items = JSON.parse(responseText);
    var choice = [Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
    var title = items[choice].title;
    var link = items[choice].link;
    var description = items[choice].description;
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    a.href = link;
    a.target = "_blank";
    a.innerHTML = title;
    p.innerHTML = description;
    var div = document.getElementById("podcast");
    div.innerHTML = "";
    div.appendChild(a);
    div.appendChild(br);
    div.appendChild(p);
};
```

Comment: Please edit your question, your question is unclear about what you are asking.

Comment: What is unclear? I have a div that .onclick activates a function which shows a piece of text. If the text is a link (which will be openend in a new tab when the link is clicked), the .onclick should not execute the function again (although the link is within the div). If the text is no link, the .onclick shows the next text, which is working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you want, you can check if target is `<a></a>` tag (link)by passing `e` as callback function parameter which contains click event information like position, target, offset position, etc.

`instanceof` keyword checks if object is instance of HTMLAnchorElement.

```js
function onclick(e){
  if(e.target instanceof HTMLAnchorElement) return console.log('Link');
  
  //body
  console.log('Not a link');
}

test.onclick = onclick;
```

```html
<div id='test'>Some text <a href='#some_link'>Some link</a></div>
```